# Create module with angular plugin in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, angular, plugins

I'm begging at angular and trying to test the angular Get Started Tutorial (https://angular.io/guide/quickstart). I'm using `angular cli` plugin in eclipse.

At the 7th part of the tutorial I'm suppose to build a new module, what the command `ng generate module app-routing --flat --module=app` should do.

I was wondering if eclipse can do it for me. I see it can make new components, new services, new pipes. But how can I get a new module with eclipse ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Which Angular Eclipse plug-in do you use? [Angular Eclipse](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/angular-eclipse), Angular IDE, ...?

Answer (score 2):

For Angular IDE at least, I don't think there is an option to do this. The good news is that you can do it manually in the eclipse terminal. If you don't already have the view open, go to 'window' -> 'show view' -> 'other' and look for 'Terminal +'. In that view, you can enter the command to create your module:

> ng generate module app-routing --flat --module=app

While it is an extra step, you end up with the same results. Hope that helps.